# OneDrive doesn't upload local *.TMP files -- workaround?

Tags: sync, onedrive, temporary-files

I would like to sync a folder where Microsoft Word (and PowerPoint, for that matter) store their temporary autosave files, with OneDrive.

That way, if Word or PowerPoint crash and for some reason some of the local autosave files are deleted, I can restore the last state of my documents from the OneDrive backup.

However, it seems that OneDrive does not sync files with the *.tmp file extension, which Word and PowerPoint create on auto-saving.

Does anyone know of a setting or trick to get OneDrive to sync *.tmp files anyway?

Comment: Hopefully someone has an answer for you, but looking at this, I get the impression that ignoring tmp files is hardcoded: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/onedrive-is-stuck-on-sync-pending-4aad2094-7cf2-4b04-9451-10f16144376c

Comment: The only trick is to zip them up, or rename them temporarily.

Comment: Why go all the trouble? You can set autosave using group policy to automatically save to onedrive.

Comment: Really? Would you perhaps have a link to a guide on how to do that? Note that I do not want to automatically save the currently open documents to OneDrive (these can be anywhere and not necessarily in the OneDrive folder), but specifically the backup files that Word or PowerPoint create.